# how to add account name in the url and redirect or get the records based on account name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

For Ex:- http://localhost:3000/account_name/dashboard
All user will have an account name based on their account name I need
attach all the URL to be attached in front of account_name and need all the records based on that account name

Basically, how the GitHub will redirect to our repository like that I need to implement.
for ex:- https://github.com/account_name/ecommerce

I have no idea what I have to search it in google

I came across redirect based on constraint but I'm not sure.

association:- User has_one association with the account.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this in your **session or login controller**. If the user is signing in your application.

```
def create
    @user = User.find_by(email: params[:email]) #you can try your own sign_in method
     if @user && @user.valid_password?(params[:password])
      redirect_to get_redir_link(@user) #you can call the redirect link here
    else
      redirect_to login_path
    end
end


def get_redir_link(user)
    account_name = user.account_name #by using user find the account name for your scenarios
    return "#{account_name}/dashboard" #return the url whatever you want
end
```

In my application i have done like. You can make use of it.

Comment: but I may get a routing error if I attached account_name like this. Although there are many other links I need to do it in the same manner.

Comment: please share the association for user and account_name based on that we can do it.